Grouping Multiple Parts into a Single Model
I wanted to create a banner for my YouTube channel, so I made it in Roblox Studio. After creating the models, I exported them and imported them into Blender. However, I noticed that the parts within each model were separate, and the textures were incorrect. Is it possible to group all of those parts into a single model in Blender? I hope this explanation makes sense.


You can join mesh objects into single object by selecting them and hitting  Ctrl  +  J .
You can also use collections to manage objects in your scene which makes more sense.  M  moves objects to collections,  Shift  +  M  adds objects to collections without removing them from the ones they are in. You can also manage collections in the Outliner:

There are no rules about how you do that - the ones in my screenshot are completely random and you can make whatever collections that make sense to you in whatever way that may help you manage your scene. Objects can belong to multiple collections.
In addition to collections there is also the basic concept of object hierarchy in the scene. You may parent( Ctrl  +  P ,  Alt  +  P  to unparent) objects to other objects so they become children of those objects. This way objects lower in the hierarchy will inherit transforms from their parents(basically when you move, rotate or scale a parent all children and their children move, rotate and scale as well). This can be managed in the Outliner as well:

( Shift +drag)
